# #include<iostream> causes error when compiled with C library (Raylib) in C++ project

Tags: c++, c, linux, include, cross-compiling

I'm trying to use Raylib in my C++ project which previously worked fine on windows. Now on Linux I get loads of errors when trying to compile if any of the following is included:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cstdio>
#include<fstream>
#include<sstream>
```

The errors are made of several entries of the following: ( The list is actually too long to post it here )

```
/snap/clion/193/bin/cmake/linux/bin/cmake --build /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/cmake-build-debug --target project -j 12
[1/6] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/project.dir/Button.cpp.o
FAILED: CMakeFiles/project.dir/Button.cpp.o
/usr/bin/c++ -DGRAPHICS_API_OPENGL_33 -DPLATFORM_DESKTOP -I/home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/cmake-build-debug -I/home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/External/raylib -I/home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/External/raylib-3.7/src -I/home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/External/raylib-3.7/src/external/glfw/include -g -std=gnu++2a -MD -MT CMakeFiles/project.dir/Button.cpp.o -MF CMakeFiles/project.dir/Button.cpp.o.d -o CMakeFiles/project.dir/Button.cpp.o -c /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.cpp
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/cwchar:44,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/postypes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iosfwd:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.h:20,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.cpp:5:
/usr/include/wchar.h:600:9: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  600 |         __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/wchar.h:607:8: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  607 |        __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/wchar.h:613:9: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  613 |         __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/wchar.h:673:8: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  673 |        __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/wchar.h:680:7: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  680 |       __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/wchar.h:685:8: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  685 |        __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:461,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/c++config.h:522,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/utility:68,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/array:38,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.h:16,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.cpp:5:
/usr/include/wchar.h:693:12: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  693 | extern int __REDIRECT (vfwscanf, (__FILE *__restrict __s,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/wchar.h:697:12: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  697 | extern int __REDIRECT (vwscanf, (const wchar_t *__restrict __format,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/wchar.h:700:12: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  700 | extern int __REDIRECT_NTH (vswscanf, (const wchar_t *__restrict __s,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/cstdio:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:6545,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.h:20,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.cpp:5:
/usr/include/stdio.h:342:8: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  342 |        __gnuc_va_list __arg);
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:347:54: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  347 | extern int vprintf (const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg);
      |                                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:350:8: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  350 |        __gnuc_va_list __arg) __THROWNL;
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:359:42: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  359 |         const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |                                          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:367:9: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  367 |         __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:380:8: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  380 |        __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:433:7: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  433 |       __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:440:53: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  440 | extern int vscanf (const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |                                                     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:445:40: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  445 |       const char *__restrict __format, __gnuc_va_list __arg)
      |                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/features.h:461,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/os_defines.h:39,
                 from /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/c++/10/bits/c++config.h:522,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/utility:68,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/array:38,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.h:16,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.cpp:5:
/usr/include/stdio.h:451:12: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  451 | extern int __REDIRECT (vfscanf,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:456:12: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  456 | extern int __REDIRECT (vscanf, (const char *__restrict __format,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/stdio.h:459:12: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  459 | extern int __REDIRECT_NTH (vsscanf,
      |            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/cstdio:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ext/string_conversions.h:43,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:6545,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.h:20,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.cpp:5:
/usr/include/stdio.h:831:8: error: ‘__gnuc_va_list’ has not been declared
  831 |        __gnuc_va_list __args)
      |        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from /usr/include/c++/10/string:55,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/locale_classes.h:40,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ios:42,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/ostream:38,
                 from /usr/include/c++/10/iostream:39,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.h:20,
                 from /home/usr/CLionProjects/Project/Button.cpp:5:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h: In function ‘std::string std::__cxx11::to_string(float)’:
/usr/include/c++/10/bits/basic_string.h:6663:20: error: no matching function for call to ‘__to_xstring<std::string>(int (*)(char*, size_t, const char*, int) noexcept, const int&, const char [3], float&)’
 6663 |         "%f", __val);
      |
```

From what I could find on the internet so far it has to do with cross-compiling since Raylib is written in C and I'm using a C++ compiler, but I couldn't find a solution. Has anyone an idea?

Comment: It's hard to know, since you haven't provided a sample of representative source.  Try replacing usage of C headers in the library with C++ equivalents (e.g. replace `#include <stdio.h>` with `#include <cstdio>`).  Depending on how the compiler/library is installed there are subtle (and not-so-subtle) differences between C headers and C++ equivalents that can confuse a C++ compiler and cause incompatibilities like this.

Comment: Also, it seems you are misusing the term "cross-compiling". Cross-compiling is using a compiler on one host to build executables targeted for another host (e.g. use a cross-compiler on windows to produce a linux executable).  It is not compiling C using a C++ compiler, nor is it porting code targeting windows so it can be compiled natively on a unix box.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the problem is solved, even though I don't understand why.

```
namespace r
{
#include "raylib.h"
}

//STL
#include<iostream>

int main()
{
    
    r::BeginDrawing();
    r::ClearBackground(r::RAYWHITE);
    r::DrawText("Test", 100,100, 15, r::BLUE);
    r::EndDrawing();
    
    return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work and outputs the errors listed above. However, just including iostream BEFORE raylib solved the whole issue:

```
//STL
#include<iostream>

namespace r
{
#include "raylib.h"
}

int main()
{
    
    r::BeginDrawing();
    r::ClearBackground(r::RAYWHITE);
    r::DrawText("Test", 100,100, 15, r::BLUE);
    r::EndDrawing();
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You cannot put `#include`s in a namespace except if the library specifically gives permission to do that and any header which also includes standard library headers definitively can not allow that. `namespace r { #include "raylib.h" }` will result in undefined behavior in either case.